# String Buffer to String Builder

Tags: java

How would you convert the functions of a String Buffer to a String Builder. I know the two are very similar but I can't change my `StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();` to `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` without getting an abundance of error messages.

Here is a little code I made:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();      //Create a new String Buffer with nothing in it
for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
   sb.append("Billy ");                //Add  (first name) 
   sb.append("Scranner");              //Add  (surname)
   System.out.println(sb);             //Print the string buffer
   sb.insert(5," D");                  //Insert  " D" at the 4th character
   System.out.println(sb);             //Print the String Buffer with the middle initial
   sb.delete(5, 7);                    //Delete the character line from 4 to 6  
   sb.reverse();                       //Reverse the String Buffer 
   System.out.println(sb);             //Print the reversed String Builder
```

I apologize if my question seems unclear, TLDR; I would like to know how to obtain the same output that I get from this program using a String Builder instead of the String Buffer.

Here is what the program outputs:

> Billy Scranner
>
> Billy D Scranner
>
> rennarcS ylliB

EDIT: This is the output I get when I replace Buffer with Builder:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
     The method append(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
     The method append(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
     The method insert(int, String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
     The method delete(int, int) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
     The method reverse() is undefined for the type StringBuilder
```

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on these error messages?

Comment: @JoeC  I'll add it to the post, more readable that way

Comment: I don't think that's what your program outputs. There's new lines in there and you reversed the entire buffer, not just your name

Comment: No, according to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) they are definitely defined.  Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would allow me to reproduce this?

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but could you show me how to import `String builder` ? @Kayaman

Comment: @Kayaman You shouldn't need to import it, as it's in `java.lang`.

Comment: BTW Billy I just tried your code and changed it to `StringBuilder`, and it worked beautifully for me.

Comment: @Billy Scranner are you using IDE? If yes then click error message and it will show fix

Comment: @BillyScranner use `import java.lang.StringBuilder;`

Comment: @devツ `java.lang.*` is imported by default

Comment: @MasterYushi depends upon IDE

Comment: Here is what I see, [Code](http://imgur.com/a/hu7Ck)

Comment: @BillyScranner just add `import java.lang.StringBuilder;` Is the error same?

Comment: Yes, same exact thing. @devツ

Comment: @devツ Are you sure? I am afraid it does not, all classes in java.lang package are imported by default and you can use the functions without full classified names.

Comment: @BillyScranner This is a bug in your IDE. Please report it to them.

Comment: @devツ [Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html) states : "*A package consists of a number of compilation units. A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.*"

Comment: @MasterYushi My bad. I agree with you. Thank you for sharing specs.

Comment: Looks like it does have to do with my IDE, seeing as the same exact code works on everyone else's system.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly fine. Uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse. Weird stuff :/

Comment: @BillyScranner Glad to hear that.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no errors in replacing `StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();` to `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`

```
    import java.lang.StringBuilder;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Billy "); 
    sb.append("Scranner"); 
    System.out.println(sb); 

    sb.insert(5, " D");
    System.out.println(sb); 
    sb.delete(5, 7);

    sb.reverse(); 

    System.out.println(sb);
```

Output:

```
Billy Scranner
Billy D Scranner
rennarcS ylliB
```

Comment: you should add the output as comments in your code

Comment: @MasterYushi added output.

Comment: @MasterYushi output will be same as stated in the question. Why put that again? Answer covers the answer part. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should have the exact same output using StringBuffer and StringBuilder with the code you present.

The difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder is that StringBuffer seems overkill as it is thread-safe.

If you get errors, might be related to:

- thread issues
- Development environment not being correctly set
- Typos
- File format (sometimes you copy/paste code from a source that has invisible characters preventing you from compiling the file correctly).

From what I see in the comments, you have invisible end of lines or characters that are not in the correct encoding of your platform.